# Can't CURL HTTPS URL on WAMP but works on remote server using BASH

Tags: php, ssl, curl

Here's the BASH command I'm using on my remote server  -

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: USERNAME:PASSWORD" "https://api7.publicaster.com/Rest/Ping.svc/?format=json"
```

Here's the code on my PHP script which I run on a WAMP local test environment to request the same information.

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$encrypted_account_id = 'USERNAME';
$api_password = 'PASSWORD';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://api7.publicaster.com/Rest/Ping.svc/?format=json");
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: $encrypted_account_id:$api_password';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($server_output);
```

If on my PHP script I request the HTTP site then it returns -

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
```

If on my PHP script I request the HTTPS site then it just returns blank. I do have a self-signed SSL certificate and SSL is enabled, I can access HTTPS portions of my WAMP server but I am given a warning.

I can't figure out if this was an issue with my code or my WAMP server. Any ideas?

If I add the following to my code and try to CURL the HTTPS address I at least receive a response but it's the Unauthorized CC: private error -

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

Comment: was wondering if you found a solution to this issue. I'm facing the exact same problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I found the answer, the issue is your curl request could not verify the ssl peer. Windows does not automatically have a CA certificate to do the validation against.

So here is what I did to get my https requests via curl fixed for wamp.
download the **cacert.pem** file here http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and place it in your PHP folder, mine was located at:
`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12`

Now open the php.ini file and find the line starting with 
`; curl.cainfo =`

un-comment that line "remove the ; in front" and add the absolute path of the cacert.pem file. Mine looked something like this:
`curl.cainfo = C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\cacert.pem`

Now restart wamp and voila! I can happily open https protocols via curl on wamp.